# hide headers in Devexpress gridcontrol

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

Can anyone tell me how to hide the header in DevExpress gridcontrol..?? I'm using C#.. All I want is a matrix of cells with NO header row with captions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go the run designer of the grid view, then try to modify the prorety of show groupe panel and make it false.(Feature Browser/grouping/groupe panel/show groupe panel)

Answer (score 6):

According to their [support forum](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/106731/360573.aspx), the proper solution is to toggle the [`OptionsView.ShowColumnHeaders` property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ShowColumnHeaderstopic).

If you set the property to `false`, the control will no longer display column headers.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com) grid control you are using?
Please, use the following ShowColumnHeaders options:

- [this](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ShowColumnHeaderstopic) for DevExpress [XtraGrid](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3455) (Winforms)
- [this](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_ShowColumnHeaderstopic) for DevExpress [DXGrid](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6084) (WPF/Silverlight)
- [this](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewSettings_ShowColumnHeaderstopic) for DevExpress [ASPxGridView](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument5823) (ASP.Net)

Comment: Does not work for Winforms. There is no GridOptionsView.ShowColumnHeaders property for either a grid or a grid column.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [ShowColumnHeaders](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ShowColumnHeaderstopic) property to false.

Comment: No such property exists for a Winforms XtraGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to do it programatically.  For Winforms XtraGrid.

Run the designer. (by clicking on the control in design view, then clicking on the tiny black triangle)

Under Options, expand OptionsView. Within Options.OptionsView find ShowColumnHeaders. Set it = False